# CGroups memory subsystem

Tags: kernel, ram, process, cgroup

I want to know if I can set dynamic limits to the memory subsystem in a cgroup. Currently I have OOM disabled and a dummy process to test the control group, when the limit in memory is reached, the process freezes (as expected) but when I try to set a larger limit (like 2 times more memory), the `echo` command fails and the process stays frozen.

How can I set dynamic memory usage limits in a cgroup without moving the processes to another cgroup with the new limits set?

Answer (score 1):

When you mention "dynamic limits" using cgroups, you need to be a little more specific on what you are looking for. Its best to provide an example of what your app and cgroup does along with the cgconfig.conf. This would give us better picture.

Although cgroups, allows limiting a process to certain amount of memory using `memory.limit_in_bytes` in cgconfig.conf, it only sets the upper bound and does not complain if your process uses a lower limit. Therefore, I am not sure if you require cgroups in this case.

Therefore, if your program is allocating memory dynamically you may also need to check how much of memory is being over commited. Check the kernel tunables using `sysctl -a | grep overcommit` and change to always overcommit regardless of whether memory is available or not.

Comment: Hi, what I'm trying to do exactly is a simple container for computing intensive processes. With the CGroup, I want to limit the memory consumption of those processes so they won't be so invasive to other user's applications. There will be a daemon which samples the system resources (CPU workload, total memory available, etc.) and when it detects that the system is relatively "idle" it will change the CGroups memory limits so it can do more work (the inverse is needed too, when the resource usage for the common user's applications is high, the daemon should minimize the cgroups resources).

Comment: Did you look into the documentation or examples for `memory.limit_in_bytes`, if so its best to share the cgconfig.conf and cgred.conf, if you already have something which is not working.

Comment: First try to get the cgroups working without the daemon/script what you have. I have not tried anything like this to dynamic modify the cgroups. Also unsure of how you are making those changes during run time, but keep in mind that you would need to restart `cgred` and `cgconfig` everytime the daemon makes the changes to the conf files.

Comment: Hi, i'm not using cgconfig.conf or cgred because i'm just mounting the subsystems and creating the crgoup with libcgroup and terminal commands. I believe my actual problem is really how to overcome an "under_oom" situation, when that flag is set to 1 in the oom_control the processes freeze i am not able to change the memory limit parameters anymore :/

Comment: Then possibly that you are using `cgset`, `cgexec` and `cgcreate` which is non-persistant way of using control groups, although, its ok for testing. Check whether the process is in the cgroup you created. To check which cgroup a process is in use cmds:
1. ps o cgroup <pid>
2. cat /proc/<pid>/cgroup

Answer (score 1):

Well, after some research I've found that some parameters in a cgroup cannot be modified when there are tasks on it.

Sadly, the memory limit parameters are one of those.

I think my last option is to use the task migration feature and create cgroups with new memory limits on demand.

Comment: Did your suggestion to create-on-the-fly-new-cgroup-with-more-memory-and-migrate-processes work eventually?